# How can I move collapsed elements across my website with the button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a kind of nested collapse feature in html but was wondering how I can move the first card within the "Zelda Playlist" right below the button. Nothing seems to work and it just seems super buggy. I've changed positions and tried the left, top, bottom, and right features, but it remains bugged out in the corner. Also if there is a way to move both elements together that would be even better.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Faster One">
  <title>My Webpage</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button style="position:absolute; left:90%; top:34%;" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
            Zelda Playlist
        </button>
  <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample" style="width:28%;">
    <div class="card card-body">
      <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
        <div class="card" style="width:99%;">
          <div class="card-header" id="headingOne" style="text-align:center">
            <h2 class="mb-0">
              <button class="btn btn-secondary text-center collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                                    Dragon Roost Island - Wind Waker
                                </button>
            </h2>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
            <div class="card-body" style="text-align:center">
              <audio controls>
                                    <source src="dragonroost.mp3">
                                </audio>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card" style="width:99%;">
          <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo" style="text-align:center">
            <h2 class="mb-0">
              <button class="btn btn-secondary text-center collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                                    Gerudo Valley - Ocarina of Time
                                </button>
            </h2>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionExample">
            <div class="card-body" style="text-align:center">
              <audio controls>
                                    <source src="gerudo.mp3">
                                </audio>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card" style="width:99%;">
          <div class="card-header" id="headingThree" style="text-align:center">
            <h2 class="mb-0">
              <button class="btn btn-secondary text-center collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                                    Lost Woods - Ocarina of Time
                                </button>
            </h2>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordionExample">
            <div class="card-body" style="text-align:center">
              <audio controls>
                                    <source src="lostwoods.mp3">
                                </audio>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="functions.js"></script>
  <audio src="coin.wav" autostart="false" width="0" height="0" id="coin" enablejavascript="true">
        <audio src="death.wav" autostart="false" width="0" height="0" id="death" enablejavascript="true">
            <script>
                var death = document.getElementById("death");
                death.volume = 0.2;
            </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code would be more manageable using stylesheet. as shown.

To move the "Zelda Playlist" right below the button, all you need is a wrapper that encapsulates the button and the playlist.

After that, migrate the positioning css from the button to the wrapper (position of any element is block by default, which means if the button is above the playlist within the wrapper, the button and playlist is vertically-aligned by default).

Set to right:5% instead of left: 95%, this allows the wrapper items to align right by default.

Set the button to float right and margin-left:100% to ensure that it's on the right side.

Set collapse div to 100% to ensure that the whole collapsed div is not shrunk

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Faster One">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <title>My Webpage</title>
  <style>
      .collapsibleWrapper {
          position:absolute; right: 5%; top:34%;
      }
      .collapsibleWrapper .btn-primary {
          max-width: 80px;
          float: right;
          margin-left: 100%;
      }
      .collapse, .collapsing {
          width: 100% !important;
      }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="collapsibleWrapper">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
            Zelda Playlist
        </button>
  <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample" style="width:28%;">
    <div class="card card-body">
      <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
        <div class="card" style="width:99%;">
          <div class="card-header" id="headingOne" style="text-align:center">
            <h2 class="mb-0">
              <button class="btn btn-secondary text-center collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                                    Dragon Roost Island - Wind Waker
                                </button>
            </h2>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
            <div class="card-body" style="text-align:center">
              <audio controls>
                                    <source src="dragonroost.mp3">
                                </audio>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card" style="width:99%;">
          <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo" style="text-align:center">
            <h2 class="mb-0">
              <button class="btn btn-secondary text-center collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                                    Gerudo Valley - Ocarina of Time
                                </button>
            </h2>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionExample">
            <div class="card-body" style="text-align:center">
              <audio controls>
                                    <source src="gerudo.mp3">
                                </audio>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card" style="width:99%;">
          <div class="card-header" id="headingThree" style="text-align:center">
            <h2 class="mb-0">
              <button class="btn btn-secondary text-center collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                                    Lost Woods - Ocarina of Time
                                </button>
            </h2>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordionExample">
            <div class="card-body" style="text-align:center">
              <audio controls>
                                    <source src="lostwoods.mp3">
                                </audio>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="functions.js"></script>
  <audio src="coin.wav" autostart="false" width="0" height="0" id="coin" enablejavascript="true">
        <audio src="death.wav" autostart="false" width="0" height="0" id="death" enablejavascript="true">
            <script>
                var death = document.getElementById("death");
                death.volume = 0.2;
            </script>
            </audio>
           </audio>  
    </body>
</html>
```